# How to properly set the value of a custom radiobutton control in an Angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a simple custom radio button control.  HTML:

```
<label class="radiobutton-container" >
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <input type="radio" [value]="value" [name]="name" [disabled]="disabled" (change)="handleChange($event)" [checked]="checked"/>
    <span [ngClass]="{'checkbase': true,
    'checkmark' : checked
    }"></span>
</label>
```

In general it works fine, I can tell if it is checked and put it into groups, etc.  But - when I use it in a form, I just the value of the group as "true" instead of the value of the component:

```
<form #form="ngForm" >
    <my-radiobutton [ngModel]="mymodel" [name]="'options'" [value]="'value1'" >Value 1</my-radiobutton>
    <my-radiobutton [ngModel]="mymodel"   [name]="'options'" [value]="'value2'" >Value 2</my-radiobutton>
    <my-radiobutton [ngModel]="mymodel"  [name]="'options'" [value]="'value3'" >Value 3</my-radiobutton>
</form>
<p>form value:</p>
<pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
```

When I print the value of the form, it is just "options: true", instead of "value1", "value2", etc.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array instead of calling the component again and again, Please refer the below code
**App.component.html**

```
`<form> 
   <app-my-radiobutton [inputList]="radioList" 
   (changedInput)="onValueChange($event)"></app-my-radiobutton>
</form>
<pre *ngIf="title">
   {{title.form.value | json}}
</pre>`
```

**App.component.ts**

`title: NgForm;`

`radioList = ['Male', 'Female'];`

`onValueChange(event) {
     this.title = event
    }`

**Myradiobutton.Component**

`@Input() inputList = [];`

`@Output() changedInput = new EventEmitter<any>();`

`inputData: string;`
  `constructor() { }`

`ngOnInit() {}`

`onChange(event, form) {
     this.changedInput.emit(form)
  }`

**Myradiobutton.HTML**

```
`<div class="container">
    <form #form="ngForm">
        <div *ngFor="let item of inputList; let i = index">
            <input type="radio" id="{{item+i}}" name="gender" value="{{item}}" 
            [(ngModel)]="item" (change)="onChange($event, form)">
            <label for="male">{{item}}</label><br> 
        </div>
    </form>
</div>`
```

**Output**

{
  "gender": "Male"
} or {
  "gender": "FeMale"
}

Comment: So basically the component is a radiobuttongroup instead of a lone radio button?

Comment: Yes, No need to call the component multiple times when it has to be in group

Comment: This solves my problem.  I am still curious why the radio button doesn't send the value in my initial example but this approach is even cleaner.